# Capture inputs to subprocess.run()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have an interactive command line exe file on Windows, wrote by someone else. When the program has an exception, it terminates and all my inputs to the program are lost.

So I'm writing a python program that calls a blocking subprocess with `subprocess.run()` and captures all inputs to `stdin` for backup, without affecting the interaction to the subprocess. But I didn't find a way to capture the inputs. How do I do this in Python?

An example (but not working) code would be like:

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run(['program.exe'], stderr = subprocess.PIPE,text=True)

# Interact with the program. Wait for it to finish.

if subprocess_object.returncode != 0:
   open('input_backup.txt','w').write(process.stdin)  # Won't work
   open('error_backup.txt','w').write(process.stderr)
```

One idea I had is to override an `StringIO` object and give it two stream, one `sys.stdin` and one file stream to `write()` to. Then assign sys.stdin to a instance of that overrided class. But I didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: I avoid Windows whenever I can, so not posting this as an answer, but a pipe to `tee stdin` would fix it trivially on a Unixy platform.