# How to override sys.stdin to duplicate the input stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm writing a Python 3.6 program on Windows to record all the **input** to a subprocess for backup. (I cannot modify the subprocess code as the real program is a commercial product (exe file) and I don't have the source code.)

I tried the following code, and it doesn't work. The text only shows in the terminal, and the txt files used for logging are empty.

**Main.py**:

```
import subprocess
import sys    

class dup_stream():
    def __init__(self, original_stream, file):
        self.original_stream = original_stream
        self.log = open(file, 'a')

    def write(self, message):
        self.log.write(message)
        self.original_stream.write(message)

    def fileno(self):
        return self.original_stream.fileno()


completed_process = subprocess.run('python Hello.py',
                                   stdin=dup_stream(sys.stdin, 'stdin.txt'),
                                   stderr=dup_stream(sys.stderr, 'stderr.txt'),
                                   stdout=dup_stream(sys.stdout, 'stdout.txt'))
```

**Hello.py**:

```
name = input("Your name:") # e.g. "Jane Doe"
print('Hello,',name)
```

---

Expected result:

In terminal:

```
Your name: Jane Doe
Hello, Jane Doe
```

stdin.txt:

```
Jane Doe
```

stdout.txt:

```
Your name:
Hello, Jane Doe
```

I've asked a more general question before ([Capture inputs to subprocess.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810417/capture-inputs-to-subprocess-run)), but there aren't any practical answer.

Comment: Maybe you can try async subprocess https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-subprocess.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture inputs to subprocess.run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810417/capture-inputs-to-subprocess-run)

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess` will very likely bypass this because it uses the `fileno` directly.

Use `stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE`.
However, it is not totally straightforward how to forward everything then. Maybe the easiest way is to have 3 threads, one for each `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`, where you read from the source (e.g. `sys.stdin`, or `process.stdout`) and then write it to the file and to the target (`process.stdin`, or `sys.stdout`).
See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421757/live-output-from-subprocess-command) for some other options.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which I solved with a wrapper class, which I passed instead of sys.stdin (i only needed to log read and readline):

```
class StdinWrapper(object):

  def __getattribute__(self, name):
    attr = getattr(sys.stdin, name)

    if name == 'readline' or name == 'read':
      def method_with_log(*args, **kwargs):
        result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
        f = open('/tmp/log-input', 'a')
        f.write(result)
        f.close()
        return result
      return method_with_log

    return attr
```